# swiftui - ios16 navigation link changes

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have read many articles regarding the changes for IOS 16 and navigationLinks, yet I'm still lost in what I'm trying to achieve. All of the examples I have seen have navigation links that are clicked and then based off of that you present a different view on the stack. My code doesn't have navigation stack, nor does it have a navigation view. It simply has several "hidden" links (empty view) that are automatically invoked when the isActive variable is true (which is false by default).

Here is the flow of one example:

1. User clicks the submit button
2. Web REST API is invoked (Asynchronous results come back)
3. If REST API is successful, set isActive to true to display a different view

So there is no clicking of the link itself. I'm thinking based off of the options, somehow including a navigation stack and using path to append to upon the API return would work? Not sure.

The other thing is that I have a toolbar on the top that has the navigation views. None of these examples use the navigation links along with the toolbar (Maybe people don't use the toolbar much anymore??).

Each one of my views is a struct in a different file, and calling these structs with the navigation stack and the toolbar seems to cause some problems (the back button is below the toolbar, etc.) that I'll have to correct. Most of the examples shows the .destination inside the same file/struct (e.g. they have, for example, the entire next view content within the .destination area (e.g. a vstack with, say a button, and some text, etc)).

I'll paste some code if it's helpful, but ideally I want to perform the same actions - upon the return of an API call, I want to switch views programmatically by simply changing a variable, or some other simple mechanism. No clicking of the navigation link will occur.

I liked the old model better. Seems easier to me.

-Jim

Comment: Yes, use a `NavigationStack` and manipulate the path